# is there a Python NumPy function to flatten selected axes of an NumPy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape, flatten

I have a 3d array "A" of shape (m, n, k)

and I want to change it to the shape (m, j) where j = m*k

one method i have used is

```
A = np.arange(27).reshape([3,3,3])
A

>> array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
           [ 3,  4,  5],
           [ 6,  7,  8]],

          [[ 9, 10, 11],
           [12, 13, 14],
           [15, 16, 17]],

          [[18, 19, 20],
           [21, 22, 23],
           [24, 25, 26]]])
```

```
m = A.shape[0]
m

>> 3
```

```
A = A.reshape([m, -1])
A.shape

>> (3, 9)
```

```
A

>> array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
          [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
          [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]])
```

but I want to know wether there is a function that can be used to reshape an array without calculating "m"

something like

```
A.flatten_axes(axis=[1, 2])
```

so it flattens the nested arrays and leaves the first axis "0" intact

Comment: What's wrong with `A.reshape(A.shape[0], -1)`?

Comment: I am using this to make a neural network, there is nothing wrong with it, its just that
Im making small little optimisations to make the code faster, and if I can skip the `m = A.shape[0]` step, it will save some time

Comment: `shape` is a member variable and accessing it happens in constant time. Even if there was a function like you described, I believe it had to access that variable internally, so there wouldn't be difference. 


 “The real problem is that programmers have spent far too much time worrying about efficiency in the wrong places and at the wrong times; premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming.”
~ The Art of Computer Programming, Donald Knuth~